# I should have 20GB of swap space, but I apparently have no swap space at all

Tags: swap

When I installed Ubuntu I set aside about 20GB for my swap space. However, when I run the `top` command I am told that I have no swap space at all. Here's the system summary provided by `top`:

```
top - 16:01:25 up 21:18,  2 users,  load average: 0.10, 0.18, 0.28
Tasks: 259 total,   1 running, 258 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.5 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8063668 total,  4532556 used,  3531112 free,   315764 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  2806168 cached Mem
```

I recently installed another Linux distro on my computer and I am worried that I accidently removed Ubuntu's swap space when I partitioned my hard drive.

Does anyone have any recommendations for recovering my swap space?

Comment: `cat /etc/fstab | grep swap` will show you where your swap partition is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that what happened is that when you installed the new Linux distro, you told it to use the old swap partition and it was formatted.

Since partitions are nowadays referenced in /etc/fstab by their UUID, if the partition was formatted, it now has a new UUID and Ubuntu can't find it anymore.

The quickest solution would be to find the new UUID (`sudo blkid | grep swap`) and update /etc/fstab accordingly, but beware, if both OSes share the same swap partition, hibernating one OS and boot into the other will wipe your hibernated session (since all memory contents is written in the swap partition when hibernating). As long as you don't use hibernate, this will be OK though, but the best choice would be to allocate a swap partition for each OS.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was only able to try this solution out today and it seems to work great. Thanks a lot.